# Good Web hosts that support Ruby and Python?

Tags: python, ruby, django, apache, ruby-on-rails-3

I love Python and Ruby equally and I simply cannot standardize on one. I love Heroku, but it can get a speck pricey and is totally specific to Rails.

Is there a decently inexpensive host, or many, that *adequately* supports both Ruby and Python frameworks as well as offering common LAMPish support?

**Yeah... I wanna know if I can just have it all for cheap (*sigh*).**

I'm mostly interested in this for development and startups... scalability is not a big deal, but very welcome.

Comment: This question probably belongs on superuser or serverfault, though I'm not sure if either of them are open towards recommendations either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're going for cheap, you'll need to go with shared hosting. VPS solutions will cost you more or less double what you pay for shared hosting.

Anyway, for shared hosting, I'll recommend [**dreamhost.com**](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?427390). They obviously support standard LAMP, and performance is pretty good in my experience.

Further more, they support Ruby and Python apps via [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). Deployment is pretty easy (granted - not Heroku-easy), and the performance is not bad. I'd definitely give it a try.

Comment: long-time dreamhost user (not for Ruby and Python) but dreamhost is definitely a nice service. easy to work with and they have some nice services.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [lowendbox.com](http://www.lowendbox.com/) - they review and have coupons for cheap VPS providers. The one I ended up going with ([clubuptime.com](http://www.clubuptime.com/)) had a 50% off deal when I signed up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out. I've never heard of lowendbox... that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I use rackspace, it's 10$ /month for the basic setup, they just give you a clean install of whatever OS you want so it will support any packages/configurations you choose to install.

Comment: Very cool. Hard to say no to Rackspace for some $20 per month (based on my estimate of bandwidth usage).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webfaction.com/ - hands down. They do Django & Rails in a shared environment — and whilst I prefer VPS's myself, it's a pretty good solution if you're just starting out. No need to be a sys-admin.

Comment: I have about 15 sites currently, and roughly 800 tables (mostly wordpress and drupal, atm... but Rails and Django sites are coming), that I need to migrate. I'm not sure if I'm in VPS territory or Shared hosting for performance needs. Webfaction does look good though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm in accordance with elithrar. I switched to webfaction and I'm very happy with the change. They've a very good support (I got answers in less than half hour for my problems/questions) and when my question is got by one of the IT guys, the same guy cares about all the subsequent communications until problem, doubts are resolved.

They're cheap too and have very good support to do almost anythong you could need. Just compile what you need and install it in your home by ssh access and ready to go.

I'm not from webfaction, but this is my experience with them.

Hope this could help you.